# How do I add a ViewController to a UITabBarController and load it Programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I am trying to put a custom viewController into a UITabBarController, and then present it. but when I try what I have below all I get is a blank screen with a blank Tab Bar at the bottom.

```
@IBAction func didOpenTabs(_ sender: Any) {
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    let vc = ViewController()

    let controllers = [vc]

    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers

    self.present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I need access to the view controller because the view controller will need to load data from a variable and also save data to the same variable when it closes.

I feel like I am doing something wrong at a fundamental level but am not familiar enough with swift to determine what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't assign the `viewControllers` before the `viewDidLoad` is called, since the inner `UITabBar` is not yet initialized, hence to solve the issue you may subclass your `UITabBarController` to make sure you setup those `viewControllers` in the right place (`viewDidLoad`), eventually your code might be:

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController:UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vc1 = UIViewController()
        vc1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        vc1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .bookmarks, tag: 0)

        let vc2 = UIViewController()
        vc2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        vc2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .history, tag: 1)

        viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func showTabVc() {
        self.present(MyTabBarController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```